# Xcode Swift 2 Variable Declaration (Instance Member cannot be used on type view controller)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am working on a project that sends some HTTP commands with an IP address that the user defines in a text field. The IP address is essentially piped into many different functions for my app. As I have done this I keep running into the "Instance member cannot be used on type" error. At the fundamentals of variable declaration, what would be the correct way to do the following? I will have about 40-50 different requests.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myIPaddress: UITextField!
var baserequest = "http://\(myIPaddress):8088/api/?function="
var requestA = "\(baserequest)myFunctionA&value=abc"
var requestB = "\(baserequest)myFunctionB&value=xyz"
var requestC = "\(baserequest)myFunctionC&value=123"
...
...
```

I am not sure if this matters but because we are using HTTP commands one of the declarations looks like this

```
var program1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(baseRequest)activeinput&input=1" )!)
```

*** UPDATE ***

I am not sure what my issue is. Here is the code I have and it's still throwing that error. On

```
var request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(baserequest)activeinput&input=1" )!)
```

So this is my entire code

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (String?, NSError?) -> Void) {
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {
        callback("", error)
        return
    }

    callback(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding), nil)
}
task.resume()
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBOutlet weak var vmixip: UITextField!
var baserequest: String = ""

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    updateBaseRequest(textField.text!)
}

func updateBaseRequest(vmixip: String) {
    baserequest = "http://\(vmixip):8088/api/?function="
}

var request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(baserequest)activeinput&input=1" )!)
@IBAction func Program1(sender: UIButton) {
    if let image = UIImage(named:"g1") {
        sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    }
    httpGet(request1) { string, error in
        guard error == nil && string != nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        print(string!) //
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: You have a couple of problems, 1, you would need to refer to `myIPaddress.text` to get the string in the text field, but more importantly you can't use the value at that point anyway because you end to update `baseRequest` and all of the other variables when the user changes the field, so you are going to need to write code in something like the UiTextFieldDelegate to do that

Comment: Hi Seth. Would you consider upvoting any of the answers you receive, and/or accepting one of them? This is how we reward helpful answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You should be initializing the request variables in a function after you have the user's IP address. The error is trying to tell you that the default value of variables [can't something that hasn't been initialized yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351343/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type) (`myIPaddress`).

Something like:

```
@IBAction func addressEntered(sender: UIButton) {
    // NOTE: Use myIPaddress.text to get the text
    baserequest = "http://\(myIPaddress.text):8088/api/?function="
    requestA = "\(baserequest)myFunctionA&value=abc"
    requestB = "\(baserequest)myFunctionB&value=xyz"
    requestC = "\(baserequest)myFunctionC&value=123"
}
```

In addition, you'd need to declare those variables as optionals if you need them throughout the class:

```
class MyClass {
    var requestA: String?
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could turn your request variables into [computed properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

```
class MyClass {
    var baseRequest: String?
    var requestA: String {
        // Beware, this would crash if used before baseRequest was initialized
        return "\(baseRequest!)myFunctionA&value=abc"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Instance member cannot be used on type" error is being caused by referencing values that are not available yet.

For example, you can't have

```
var myValue = "something"
```

and then reference that value again in

```
var myValueAgain = self.myValue
```

The initialization of properties doesn't work like code in a function. This is because "self" is not available until the object is created. You are trying to access "self" before it is available.

---

Another problem is that you are referring to a UITextField in

```
var baserequest = "http://\(myIPaddress):8088/api/?function="
```

whereas the value with the String type that you can use is in

```
myIPaddress.text
```

Assigning the value at initialization also will not update the value automatically as it changes in your UI.

Handling the change of the text field requires implementing methods for `UITextFieldDelegate` such as

- `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`
- `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

You use those methods to update your baserequest when the user updates the text in the text field.

Therefore, your class will have something like this

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var baserequest: String

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        updateBaseRequest(textField.text)
    }

    func updateBaseRequest(ipAddress: String) {
        baserequest = "\(ipAddress)..."
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure what I am missing here. This is my code.

Comment: If you make a function to get your requests based on the request number or something such as `func getRequest(requestNumber: Int) -> String` then you will avoid that problem where the instance members cannot be used. You'll need to remove `var request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(baserequest)activeinput&input=1" )!)` to clear the error. Replacing it by a function is my recommendation. Every time you need to get the URL, you would use the function.

Comment: @SethHaberman I've updated my answer to better explain what is happening. Let me know if that helps.