# Instance member cannot be used on type - error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums

I have been having a strange error, and have had no luck in trying to fix it. I've got some linked files, and I'm calling a function in one file (`ViewController`) that's defined in another file (`Sign.swift`). The function in `Sign.swift` creates output defined in another file (`GameState.swift`). I'm not sure what's wrong with this, I've done a lot of research, and even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351343/instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type) didn't help. (errors under code).

`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var computerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rockButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var paperButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scissorsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playAgain: UIButton!

    @IBAction func rockButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        computerLabel.text = randomSign()
        var playerChoice = Sign.rock
        var output = Sign.checkInputs(playerChoice, computerLabel.text) //Error 1 is here
    }

    @IBAction func paperButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func scissorsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func playAgainPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }


}
```

`Sign.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit

let randomChoice = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 2)

func randomSign() -> String {
    let sign = randomChoice.nextInt()
    if sign == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    else if sign == 1 {
        return ""
    }
    else {
        return "✌️"
    }
}

enum Sign {
    case rock, paper, scissors

    var emoji: String {

        switch self {

        case .rock:
            return ""
        case.paper:
            return ""
        case.scissors:
            return "✌️"
        }
    }

    func checkInputs(_ user: Sign, opponent: Sign) -> String {
        var outcome = GameState.draw
        if (opponent == .rock) {
            if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .draw
            }
            else if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .win
            }
            else {
                outcome = .lose
            }
        }
        else if (opponent == .paper) {
            if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .lose
            }
            else if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .draw
            }
            else {
                outcome = .win
            }
        }
        else if (opponent == .scissors) {
            if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .win
            }
            else if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .lose
            }
            else {
                outcome = .draw
            }
        }

        return outcome //Error 2 is here
    }

}
```

`GameState.swift`:

```
import Foundation

enum GameState {
    case start, win, lose, draw

    var text: String {

        switch self {
        case.start:
            return "Game started!"

        case.win:
            return "You win!"

        case.lose:
            return "You lose!"

        case.draw:
            return"It's a draw!"
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting errors in both files: Error 1 (commented line in `ViewController.swift`) has the below error message:

> Instance member 'checkInputs` cannot be used on type 'Sign'; did you
>   mean to use a value of this type instead?

Unfortunately I don't understand what I'm mean to fix from the above message, I'm new to Swift.

Error 2 (commented line in `Sign.swift`) has this message:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'GameState' to return type
>   'String'

Again, I don't understand what's happening here. I don't have any errors in my `GameState.swift` file though, so that means all errors should be in `ViewController.swift` and `Sign.swift`. How should I fix these errors?

**EDIT:** I have updated my code, it now looks like this:

`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func computerChoose() {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var computerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rockButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var paperButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scissorsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playAgain: UIButton!

    @IBAction func rockButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var random = randomSign()
        var stringRandom = ""
        switch random {
        case .rock :
            stringRandom = ""
        case .paper:
            stringRandom = ""
        case .scissors:
            stringRandom = "✌️"
        }
        var playerChoice = Sign.rock
        var output = Sign.checkInputs(random)
        computerLabel.text = stringRandom
    }

    @IBAction func paperButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func scissorsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func playAgainPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }


}
```

`Sign.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import GameplayKit

let randomChoice = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: 2)

func randomSign() -> Sign {
    let sign = randomChoice.nextInt()
    if sign == 0 {
        return .rock
    }
    else if sign == 1 {
        return .paper
    }
    else {
        return .scissors
    }
}

enum Sign {
    case rock, paper, scissors

    var emoji: String {

        switch self {

        case .rock:
            return ""
        case.paper:
            return ""
        case.scissors:
            return "✌️"
        }
    }

    static func checkInputs(_ opponent: Sign) -> GameState {
        var outcome = GameState.draw
        if (opponent == .rock) {
            if (emoji == "") { //Error Emoji
                outcome = .draw
            }
            else if (emoji == "") { //Error Emoji
                outcome = .win
            }
            else {
                outcome = .lose
            }
        }
        else if (opponent == .paper) { //Error Emoji
            if (emoji == "") {
                outcome = .lose
            }
            else if (emoji == "") { //Error Emoji
                outcome = .draw
            }
            else {
                outcome = .win
            }
        }
        else if (opponent == .scissors) {
            if (emoji == "") { //Error Emoji
                outcome = .win
            }
            else if (emoji == "") { //Error Emoji
                outcome = .lose
            }
            else {
                outcome = .draw
            }
        }

        return outcome
    }

}
```

*Note:* New errors are on every line with the comment `Error Emoji`, with this error message:

> Instance member 'emoji' cannot be used on type 'Sign'

`GameState.swift`: **Unchanged**.

I would appreciate all help with this.

Comment: `checkInputs` is instance function, not`static` function. You need either call it with value of type `Sign` or make it `static`. Latter looks like it.

Comment: You need to know that in OOP, there are Instance/Object methods and Class methods. It's up to the language on how define them (static or not in Swift), but as in Swift, your are calling the `checkInputs()` method as it was a Class one and not an instance one, but it's defined as an instance method. For the other issue, did you mean `return outcome.text` instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to use the method without an *instance*, you need to declare the method as `static`.

```
static func checkInputs(_ user: Sign, opponent: Sign) -> String
```

Note: You do not seem to using the `user` that you pass. IMO you could skip asking for that parameter and use it as an instance method with `playerChoice`.

```
func checkInputs(opponent: Sign) -> String {
    // Your logic
}
```

And then use it like this

```
playerChoice.checkInputs(opponent: randomSign())
```

The second error is because you are trying to return an instance of `Sign` instead of a `String`. You need to either change the return type to `Sign` or covert the `Sign` in `outcome` to `String` - `outcome.text` like @Larme pointed out?

Comment: I apologise if this sounds basic, but what exactly is an *instance*?

Comment: @JBDouble05 `playerChoice` that you create just before calling `checkInputs` is an _instance_ of the `Sign`.

Comment: Just implemented your solution, and on all my `if` statements in `checkInputs`, the following error comes up: `Instance member 'emoji' cannot be used on type 'Sign'` Any suggestions?

Comment: @JBDouble05 Can you update your code as an edit in your question **below your current question** and point to where it shows the error?

Comment: Done now, sorry for late reply - I'm on AEST

Comment: @JBDouble05 it seems like you combined both my solutions. If you are going with my second approach, then your method should not be static. My answer clearly doesn't say static in the second approach.

Comment: OK, I'll fix it and see what happens

Comment: @JBDouble05 sure. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: OK, it's fixed now, and it works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help!