# How to convert a computed closure property to closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, core-audio

In the [Core Audio Recorder example](https://github.com/AlesTsurko/LearningCoreAudioWithSwift2.0/blob/master/CH04_Recorder/AudioQueueRecorder/main.swift#L129https://github.com/AlesTsurko/LearningCoreAudioWithSwift2.0/blob/master/CH04_Recorder/AudioQueueRecorder/main.swift#L129) the `AudioQueueInputCallback` function is written as a variable binding outside the class `Recorder`. I am trying to use it inside a struct, but I am not able to access any instance methods. It gives the error, [Instance members cannot be used on type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53206952/10900045).

```
struct Recorder {
    private var log = Logger()
    private let utils = Utils()


    func record() {
        // ...
        AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, audioQueueInputCallback, &recorder, nil, nil, 0, &queue)
    }

    private let audioQueueInputCallback: AudioQueueInputCallback = { (inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, inQueue: AudioQueueRef,
                                                                  inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef, inStartTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                                                                  inNumPackets: UInt32, inPacketDesc: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) in
        log.debug()   //  <-- error: instance member cannot be used on type Recorder

}
```

How to write `audioQueueInputCallback` inside a struct such that the instance variables can be accessed inside it?

---

Update: If I change the var to lazy as:

```
private lazy var audioQueueInputCallback: AudioQueueInputCallback = {
        (_ inUserData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, _ inQueue: AudioQueueRef,
        _ inBuffer: AudioQueueBufferRef, _ inStartTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
        _ inNumPackets: UInt32, _ inPacketDesc: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) in
    log.debug("audio queue callback")
}
```

I am getting `Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter` error.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33260808/1187415)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, you cannot pass a function to be used as a C callback function if it is declared as a method of a type. It *must* be a global (top level) or a local (inside another func). That is why the example makes it a global.

Comment: For an example, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p640systemSound/ch27p910systemSound/ViewController.swift. I've declared the C callback as a global, but I've also marked with a comment the other place in the code where it could have been declared as a local.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self inside the closure of a lazy property. So you should define 'audioQueueInputCallback' as lazy.

Comment: It gives `Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter`. error. I have updated the question to reflect the change.